# How to run 2 WSO2 Identity Server services in the same system

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I've used 5.11.0 .deb package and installed it using
**sudo dpkg -i packagename**
Now i can run wso2 IS as a service by running **sudo service wso2is-5.11.0 start**

But i dont know how to run one more service, preferably on port 9444

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily,

1. Download the WSO2 Identity Server from [here][1].
   [1]: https://wso2.com/identity-server/#
2. Extract the file to a dedicated directory. For the purposes of this scenario, this is referred to as <IS_HOME_PRIMARY> in this topic.
3. Make a copy of this folder in the same location and rename it. For the purposes of this scenario, this is referred to as <IS_HOME_SECONDARY> in this topic.
4. By default, the HTTPS port of the primary IS instance is 9443. Let this be left as it is.
5. There are two ways to set an offset to a port:(9444)

option 1: in the `<IS_HOME_SECONDARY>/bin` Pass the port offset to the server during startup. The following command starts the server with the default port incremented by 1 :
`./wso2server.sh -DportOffset=1`

option 2: Set the offset value in the <IS_HOME_SECONDARY>/repository/conf/deployment.toml file as follows:

```
[server]
offset = ""
```

Change the Offset value to 1. This changes the HTTPS port in the secondary IS instance to 9444

In this option 2, Install and run the two Identity Server instances.
Go to <IS_HOME_PRIMARY>/bin and <IS_HOME_SECONDARY>/bin in your command line and type the following command for each instance.

On Linux/Solaris: `sh wso2server.sh`

also as @ycr mentioned you can configure the WSO2 identity server as a Linux service https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/setup/installing-as-a-linux-service/#running-the-product-as-a-linux-service

Answer (score 0):

You can't start the same service multiple times with different port offsets. Hence download the product again unzip it and start it with a port offset as described [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/references/default-ports-of-wso2-products/#changing-the-offset-for-default-ports).

Comment: I've copied the service file in /etc/init.id/wso2is-5.11.0 and created a new one for the second instance. But when im running it (sudo /etc/init.d/wso2is-5.11.0-secondary start) im getting this error   /etc/init.d/wso2is-5.11.0-secondary: line 26: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input

Comment: @VaisakhGopinath the easiest way is to download a the ZIP distribution and unzip it. Set a port offset and start the second server. If you want to configure the it as a Linux service please refer this document https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/installing-as-a-linux-service/